# Are there any yautja that aren't involved in the hunt?

Tags: predator-series

In the *Predator* series, the yautja are a group of aliens that travel throughout the galaxy, hunting different species for sport. In every film in the saga, every predator we see is involved in the hunt in some way, even if they're not hunting themselves. In the dubiously canon *Aliens vs. Predator: Requiem*, we see a glimpse of the predator homeworld and see that there are skyscrapers in the distance. The fact made me wonder if there have been any yautja that don't participate in the hunt. If so, what do they do? Are there regular yautja working a 9-5 office job or handing out food at a drive-thru?

Comment: Now you've got me picturing what rush hour traffic would look like in a yautja city.  I'm visualizing a 2m+ yautja sitting in something like a battle-scarred Mini, head sticking out of the roof, combistick sticking out through were the windscreen should be, flipping off another yautja in a Volkswagen Type 2 who cut him off...

Comment: Are there any humans that aren't super-jacked marines, or Danny Glover?

Comment: https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Yaquita - Predator scientist from one of the crappy books

Comment: In one of the comic series it was suggested that only the elite caste were "predators", while lower classes were producing food, maintaining equipment etc.